# SL 5 file drag and drop app works when local, not when started from remote web page

Tags: drag-and-drop, silverlight-5.0

I am working on an app that the user can drag and drop files and directories in to.
When I start the app from the debugger, either with or w/o debugging, the app works as expected.
When I try to use the xap in a page on a remote site, I get a Security exception.

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in files)  
{  
  // _files.Enqueue(fi);  
  if (fi.Attributes == FileAttributes.Directory)
```

Attaching the debugger to the browser, I see:

+fi.Attributes  'fi.Attributes' threw an exception of type   'System.Security.SecurityException'    System.IO.FileAttributes {System.Security.SecurityException}
"File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied."

1) Why does it work when started from the debugger?
2) How can I get it working outside of the debugger?

Thanks for any insight....

Comment: Does it work when you launch it from the localhost without the debugger, like ctrl+F5?

Comment: BP:  Yes, it does work when started from the debugger (V2012) with "Start without debugging".  I copy the .html and .xap to the remote host, point the browser at the .html, and it doesn't work (starts w/o elevated trust).

Comment: So your issue is not about the debugger but the location (remote/local). If you change the subject of the question you may get more answers because I am sure more people are familiar with that issue than debugger issues.

Comment: BP: Good suggestion -- title changed.